# How to make different version labels between two branches in a git repository?

Tags: git, versioning

I have a version string in my application.
Can I append a "master" string in my master and "development" in my development branch?

For now I can merge dev to master, change a version manually to "master", merge back to dev branch, change manually back to "development". Can I avoid that merging?

*Edit*: I've found similar questions:

[best way to versionize different git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077624/best-way-to-versionize-different-git-branches)

[Show the latest commit value within a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998869/show-the-latest-commit-value-within-a-web-application)

The only solution I've found it to use an output of "git describe". But this requires to deliver a git with a sole purpose of displaying a version. Maybe git can do some automatization when merging to the specific branch?

Comment: Why do you need to know which branch the source is in within the source when you have a version control system? Just seems very redundant if not unnecessary.